# Image doesn't change when Radio button is pressed in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-viewbinding

I'm trying to change an image between three `RadioButton` in a `RadioGroup` so that each button displays a different image on the same `ImageView`. But it's not working, so clearly I'm missing something.

The button is declared in `XML`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />
```

the kotlin code for the button group is:

```
        when (binding.radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        binding.radioButtonLondon.id -> {
            binding.textClock.timeZone = "Europe/London"
            binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.london)
        }

        binding.radioButtonNewYork.id -> {
            binding.textClock.timeZone = "America/New_York"
            binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.newyork)
        }

        binding.radioButtonBaijing.id -> {
            binding.textClock.timeZone = "CST6CDT"
            binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baijing)
        }

    }
```

but this doesn't work the image doesn't change. So what am I missing?

Comment: Share the rest of your XML and code. Specifically the radio group and buttons.

Comment: You haven't posted where this code is being run (inside an ``OnCheckedChangeListener``?) or the XML for your ``RadioGroup`` - if it's an ``OnCheckedChangeListener`` it's *possible* that ``checkedRadioButtonId`` hasn't been updated yet - the listener receives the ID of the checked button as a parameter, so you should refer to that. Also for what it's worth, the example in the Android docs uses an ``onClickListener`` for this instead: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton

Comment: Also just as a general tip - you can wrap all that in a ``with(binding) { }`` and then you don't need to keep saying ``binding`` everywhere, if you like!

Answer (score 2):

I used `binding.radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId` when I should have used  `binding.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->`, when I did the change it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use onClickListener instead of OnCheckedChangeListener